# Modify a php code with $pattern function to find all images in the folders and subfolders

Tags: php

Well i am trying to edit this code to include all sub-folders, the problem is this code only search images into 1 folder, it will not search images into sub-folders.

```
Header("content-type: application/x-javascript");
$pathstring=pathinfo($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
$locationstring="http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$pathstring['dirname'] . "/";

function returnimages($dirname=".")
{
  $pattern="~\.(jpe?g|gif)$~";
  $files = array();
  if($handle = opendir($dirname))
  {
    while(false !== ($file = readdir($handle))){
        if(preg_match($pattern, $file)){
            $files[] = $file;
        }
    }

    closedir($handle);
  }

  // sort pics in reverse order
  rsort($files);

  // output images into javascript array
  foreach($files as $key => $pic)
  {
    echo "picsarray[$key] = '$pic';";
  }
}

echo 'var locationstring="' . $locationstring . '";';
echo 'var picsarray=new Array();';

returnimages();
```

The idea can someone fix this code to be able to search all images including the sub-folders.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this approach is useful to you:

```
Header("content-type: application/x-javascript");
$pathstring=pathinfo($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
$locationstring="http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$pathstring['dirname'] . "/";

function returnImages($dir = ".")
{
    $files = array_diff(scandir($dir), Array(".", ".."));
    $dir_array = Array();
    $images = array();
    $pattern="~\.(jpe?g|gif)$~";
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        $path = $dir . "/" . $file;
        if (is_dir($path)) {
            // This does the magic, if is a folder, we recursively seek for more images.
            $images = array_merge($images, returnImages($path));
        }
        else if (preg_match($pattern, $path)) {
            $images[] = $path;
        }
    }
    return $images;
}

function printSortedImages(array $images) {
    // sort pics in reverse order
    rsort($images);

    // output images into javascript array
    foreach($images as $key => $pic)
    {
        echo "picsarray[$key] = '$pic';";
    }
}

echo 'var locationstring="' . $locationstring . '";';
echo 'var picsarray=new Array();';

$images = returnImages();
printSortedImages($images);
```